# How to make one Observable sequence wait for another to complete before emitting?

Tags: javascript, observable, rxjs

Say I have an `Observable`, like so:

```
var one = someObservable.take(1);

one.subscribe(function(){ /* do something */ });
```

Then, I have a second `Observable`:

```
var two = someOtherObservable.take(1);
```

Now, I want to `subscribe()` to `two`, but I want to make sure that `one` has completed before the `two` subscriber is fired.

What kind of buffering method can I use on `two` to make the second one wait for the first one to be completed?

I suppose I am looking to pause `two` until `one` is complete.

Comment: I believe the answer to this is the .exhaustMap() method however I wouldn't pretend to know how to implement it - full description here: https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A couple ways I can think of

```
import {take, publish} from 'rxjs/operators'
import {concat} from 'rxjs'

//Method one

var one = someObservable.pipe(take(1));
var two = someOtherObservable.pipe(take(1));
concat(one, two).subscribe(function() {/*do something */});

//Method two, if they need to be separate for some reason
var one = someObservable.pipe(take(1));
var two = someOtherObservable.pipe(take(1), publish());
two.subscribe(function(){/*do something */});
one.subscribe(function(){/*do something */}, null, two.connect.bind(two));
```

Comment: I ended up using `pause` and `resume` instead of `publish` and `connect`, but example two is essentially the route I took.

Comment: Will this method always make the first observable  (`one`)  resolve before the second (`two`) inside the subscribe()-function?

Comment: Why not use `Observable.forkJoin()`?  See this link https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: @mspasiuk per the OPs requirement, they only wanted the second to subscribe *after* the first had completed. `forkJoin` subscribes simultaneously.

Comment: @paulpdaniels A question for my understanding: In the first method wouldn't it be enough to call `.pipe(take(1))` on `concat(one, two)`? So the following way: `concat(one, two).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(function() { /* do something */});`?

Comment: @Spray'n'Pray No because that would complete the subscription after receiving the first value from `one` so it wouldn't even end up subscribing to `two`

Answer (score 25):

If you want to make sure that the order of execution is retained you can use flatMap as the following example

```
const first = Rx.Observable.of(1).delay(1000).do(i => console.log(i));
const second = Rx.Observable.of(11).delay(500).do(i => console.log(i));
const third = Rx.Observable.of(111).do(i => console.log(i));

first
  .flatMap(() => second)
  .flatMap(() => third)
  .subscribe(()=> console.log('finished'));
```

The outcome would be:

```
"1"
"11"
"111"
"finished"
```

Answer (score 24):

### skipUntil() with last()

**skipUntil : ignore emitted items until another observable has emitted**

**last: emit last value from a sequence** (i.e. wait until it completes then emit)

Note that anything emitted from the observable passed to `skipUntil` will cancel the skipping, which is why we need to add `last()` - to wait for the stream to complete.

```
main$.skipUntil(sequence2$.pipe(last()))
```

Official: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/skipUntil

---

Possible issue: Note that `last()` by itself [will error](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/last) if nothing is emitted. The `last()` operator does have a `default` parameter but only when used in conjunction with a predicate. I think if this situation is a problem for you (if `sequence2$` may complete without emitting) then one of these should work (currently untested):

```
main$.skipUntil(sequence2$.pipe(defaultIfEmpty(undefined), last()))
main$.skipUntil(sequence2$.pipe(last(), catchError(() => of(undefined))
```

Note that `undefined` is a valid item to be emitted, but could actually be any value. Also note that this is the pipe attached to `sequence2$` and not the `main$` pipe.

Comment: Very clumsy demo : https://angular-vgznak.stackblitz.io
You need to click to open the console tray

Comment: Your syntax is wrong. skipUntil can't be directly attached to an observable otherwise you'll get the following error: 'Property 'skipUntil' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.' You need to first run it through .pipe()

Comment: Yes this is an old answer before pipe was required. Thanks for mentioning it. I’d update it now but I’m on my phone. Feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 22):

Here's a reusable way of doing it (it's typescript but you can adapt it to js):

```
function waitFor<T>(signal: Observable<any>) {
    return (source: Observable<T>) => signal.pipe(
        first(),
        switchMap(_ => source),
    );
}
```

and you can use it like any operator:

```
var two = someOtherObservable.pipe(waitFor(one), take(1));
```

It's basically an operator that defers the subscribe on the source observable until the signal observable emits the first event.

Comment: is there a rxswift version of this reusable function

Comment: Note there is a slight semantic difference here with what the OP requested. In this case if you request `first`, and the signal `Observable` is empty then this will error. The OPs example uses `take` which would allow the source to be empty and still run the second one.

Comment: Although this might be slightly off topic for the OP - I found my problem simply to be that I wanted an observable that communicates with NGRX to wait for an observable that's doing a separate lookup to firestore (which is notably slower than NGRX). This wait for solved it for me without any performance or memory impact - good work.

Answer (score 15):

Here is yet another possibility taking advantage of switchMap's result selector

```
var one$ = someObservable.take(1);
var two$ = someOtherObservable.take(1);
two$.switchMap(
    /** Wait for first Observable */
    () => one$,
    /** Only return the value we're actually interested in */
    (value2, value1) => value2
  )
  .subscribe((value2) => {
    /* do something */ 
  });
```

Since the switchMap's result selector has been depreciated, here is an updated version

```
const one$ = someObservable.pipe(take(1));
const two$ = someOtherObservable.pipe(
  take(1),
  switchMap(value2 => one$.map(_ => value2))
);
two$.subscribe(value2 => {
  /* do something */ 
});
```

Answer (score 6):

If the second observable is *hot*, there is [another way](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pausable.md) to do *pause/resume*:

```
var pauser = new Rx.Subject();
var source1 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).take(1);
/* create source and pause */
var source2 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000).pausable(pauser);

source1.doOnCompleted(function () { 
  /* resume paused source2 */ 
  pauser.onNext(true);
}).subscribe(function(){
  // do something
});

source2.subscribe(function(){
  // start to recieve data 
});
```

Also you can use buffered version *[pausableBuffered](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pausablebuffered.md)* to keep data during pause is on.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a custom operator written with TypeScript that waits for a signal before emitting results:

```
export function waitFor<T>(
    signal$: Observable<any>
) {
    return (source$: Observable<T>) =>
        new Observable<T>(observer => {
            // combineLatest emits the first value only when
            // both source and signal emitted at least once
            combineLatest([
                source$,
                signal$.pipe(
                    first(),
                ),
            ])
                .subscribe(([v]) => observer.next(v));
        });
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
two.pipe(waitFor(one))
   .subscribe(value => ...);
```

Comment: nice pattern! You can even do three.pipe(waitFor(one), waitFor(two), take(1))

Comment: you subscribe inside an operator that's not normal IMO

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha Why is that? It's a subscription using the `first(),` operator. I think it's safe in terms of performance.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha is correct, nested subscriptions are frowned upon in RxJS. It *may* work ok but it is an anti-pattern. In many cases it can lead to unexpected results, especially out-of-order issues. Not sure about this particular situation though.

Answer (score 2):

Here's yet another, but I feel more straightforward and intuitive (or at least natural if you're used to Promises), approach.  Basically, you create an Observable using `Observable.create()` to wrap `one` and `two` as a single Observable.  This is very similar to how `Promise.all()` may work.

```
var first = someObservable.take(1);
var second = Observable.create((observer) => {
  return first.subscribe(
    function onNext(value) {
      /* do something with value like: */
      // observer.next(value);
    },
    function onError(error) {
      observer.error(error);
    },
    function onComplete() {
      someOtherObservable.take(1).subscribe(
        function onNext(value) {
          observer.next(value);
        },
        function onError(error) {
          observer.error(error);
        },
        function onComplete() {
          observer.complete();
        }
      );
    }
  );
});
```

So, what's going on here? First, we create a new Observable.  The function passed to `Observable.create()`, aptly named `onSubscription`, is passed the observer (built from the parameters you pass to `subscribe()`), which is similar to `resolve` and `reject` combined into a single object when creating a new Promise.  This is how we make the magic work.

In `onSubscription`, we subscribe to the first Observable (in the example above, this was called `one`).  How we handle `next` and `error` is up to you, but the default provided in my sample should be appropriate generally speaking.  However, when we receive the `complete` event, which means `one` is now done, we can subscribe to the next Observable; thereby firing the second Observable after the first one is complete.

The example observer provided for the second Observable is fairly simple.  Basically, `second` now acts like what you would expect `two` to act like in the OP.  More specifically, `second` will emit the first and only the first value emitted by `someOtherObservable` (because of `take(1)`) and then complete, assuming there is no error.

#### Example

Here is a full, working example you can copy/paste if you want to see my example working in real life:

```
var someObservable = Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
var someOtherObservable = Observable.from([6, 7, 8, 9]);

var first = someObservable.take(1);
var second = Observable.create((observer) => {
  return first.subscribe(
    function onNext(value) {
      /* do something with value like: */
      observer.next(value);
    },
    function onError(error) {
      observer.error(error);
    },
    function onComplete() {
      someOtherObservable.take(1).subscribe(
        function onNext(value) {
          observer.next(value);
        },
        function onError(error) {
          observer.error(error);
        },
        function onComplete() {
          observer.complete();
        }
      );
    }
  );
}).subscribe(
  function onNext(value) {
    console.log(value);
  },
  function onError(error) {
    console.error(error);
  },
  function onComplete() {
    console.log("Done!");
  }
);
```

If you watch the console, the above example will print:

> 1
>
> 6
>
> Done!

Comment: This was the breakthrough I needed to create my own custom 'cluster(T, X, D)' operator that processes only the first X emits within timespan T from the source and emits results spaced out by D delay. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped, it was very enlightening when I realized this, too.

Answer (score 1):

well, I know this is pretty old but I think that what you might need is:

```
var one = someObservable.take(1);

var two = someOtherObservable.pipe(
  concatMap((twoRes) => one.pipe(mapTo(twoRes))),
  take(1)
).subscribe((twoRes) => {
   // one is completed and we get two's subscription.
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use result emitted from previous Observable thanks to **mergeMap** (or his alias **flatMap**) operator like this:

```
 const one = Observable.of('https://api.github.com/users');
 const two = (c) => ajax(c);//ajax from Rxjs/dom library

 one.mergeMap(two).subscribe(c => console.log(c))
```

Comment: from here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap - "If the order of emission and subscription of inner observables is important, try concatMap!"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the `delayWhen` operator.

We have two observables `one$` and `two$`. First observable emits `1` after a 1s delay then completes. Second observable emits `2` only after `one$` has emitted:

```js
const one$ = of(1).pipe(
  delay(1000),
  tap(() => console.log('one$ emitted'))
);

const two$ = of(2).pipe(
  delayWhen(() => one$),
  tap(() => console.log('two$ emitted')),
);

two$.subscribe(n => {
  console.log(`n=${n}`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@7.5.5/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
const {of} = rxjs;
const {delay, delayWhen, tap} = rxjs.operators;
</script>
```