# Get values from an array of promises

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5

I've just started learning this amazing stuff. I can't figure out how to get values from an array of promises. Here's where am at:

```
const one = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(1);
  }, 1000);
})
const two = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(2);
  }, 2000);
})
const observable = Rx.Observable.from([one, two]);
observable.subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

I get in console:

```
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
```

I'd like to get:

1. Result as an array of values `[1,2]`
2. Result as individual values in order of promise resolution `1,2`

So, basically I want to emulate:

1. `Promise.all([one, two])`
2. `Promise.resolve(1), Promise.resolve(2)`

Comment: This Post will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519645/how-can-i-make-one-rxjs-observable-sequence-wait-for-another-to-complete-before

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Static method `Observable.from()` emits each item in the array so what you have right now will just emit two `Promise` objects:

You're dealing with so called Higher-order Observables (aka Observables emitting Observables). This is in RxJS 5 easily solvable with `concatAll` or `mergeAll` depending on whether you care about the order they are specified or they can be collected as the resolve.

RxJS 5 treats Observables, Promises, iterators, array (and array like objects) the same way. This means we use your Promises just like they were Observables.

I'm using `mergeAll` here to show that the second Promise finished first even though they're defined in the opposite order `[one, two]`.

```
const one = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(1);
  }, 1000);
})
const two = new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(2);
  }, 500);
})

// Result as individual values in order of promise resolution 2,1
Rx.Observable.from([one, two])
  .mergeAll()
  .subscribe(v => console.log('mergeAll: ' + v));

// Result as an array of values [2,1]
Rx.Observable.from([one, two])
  .concatAll()
  .toArray()
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

See live demo: https://jsbin.com/tigidon/4/edit?js,console

This prints to console:

```
mergeAll: 2
mergeAll: 1
[2, 1]
```

Comment: sir, you're awesome! I love you! Thank you very much!