# how to map the observable if there is need to subscribe inside data before forming it in mapped result?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am  trying to do a subscribe of observable which formed through multiple times with map operator to build that final result.

So let say If I have outer observable  functionA() where we had subscribed to it,but there is functionB() : observable where data is coming through two observable and second observable is dependent to first one result, then how can we get the return the final mapped observable .
please check code what I need to describe:-

```
functionB() : observable<any>{
return this.datastream1().map((objectA)=>{
this.datastream2(objectA).map((objectB)=>{
return [...objectA,...objectB]
})
})
}


functionA(){

this.functionB().subscribe((data)=>{
console.log(data);
})
}
```

So in this example while I am subscribing it then I am getting the observable in console instead of getting the spreaded data coming from both observables.

how can I make wait to resolve nested observable dependencies first while 
subscribing.In this scenario both observable should be resolved and then data should be returned back to subscribing function that is *textfunctionA()*

Comment: dataStream functions are async ?

Comment: if yes then try to resolve the callback in a promise object instead of returning it

Comment: @Manish yes they are asynchronous returning observable stream.

Comment: @manish even if I subscribe the nested datastream2 inside then it won't work because subscribe will be call lately till the functionA() subscribe would have been done its work ,that's  why I am getting observable in console.

Comment: there are few ways in RX module which we want to make the outer function wait for one callback to finish .. map a function returning observable for the inside one..and use  it like a chain of functions... see [this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30519645/how-to-make-one-observable-sequence-wait-for-another-to-complete-before-emitting)

Comment: since this question is tagged with angular I assume that `datastream1()` and `datastream2()` are calls that make a `http` calls via the client `HttpClient`?

Comment: @ChrisY : Yes these makes http calls.

Comment: and `datastream2` depends on the result of `datastream1`?

Comment: @ChrisY : Yes surely it does depend on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `flatMap` (or one of its siblings) will return a new stream, with one common `.subscribe()` at the end of the chain getting the business going. There probably is a neater method of including `objectA` in the resulting stream, but this should do the job:

```
functionB() : observable<any> {
    return this.datastream1().pipe(
        flatMap(objectA => combineLatest(of(objectA), this.datastream2(objectA))
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) operator, which internally does not subscribe to the next observable until the previous is completed.

```
const datastream1 = () =>
  of([{ value: 1 }, { value: 2 }, { value: 3 }]).pipe(delay(3000));


const datastream2 = dependentData => {
  const result = [
    { value: dependentData[0].value + 100 },
    { value: dependentData[1].value + 100 },
    { value: dependentData[2].value + 100 }
  ];
  return of(result);
};

const example = datastream1().pipe(
  concatMap(val1 => datastream2(val1).pipe(map(val2 => [...val1, ...val2])))
);

example.subscribe(val => {
  val.forEach(v => console.log("Value: " + v.value));
});
```

In the example above we delay the emits of `datastream1` by 3 seconds. `datastream2` though is waiting for the completion of `datastream1` before it starts emitting.
You can try it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-night-y12ow).